# Kernel failure in the file-system

Tags: linux, kernel

Im studying Operating System for the first time, so please just dont blast me.

In my textbook i read:

> **Consider that a kernel failure in the file-system code would make it risky for the kernel to try to save its state to a file on the file
>   system before rebooting.**

I wasnt able to understand why. Can you show me ? Thanks

Comment: Please use some punctuation. `I'm`, `I`, `wasn't`, `don't`.

Comment: This should probably go on https://cs.stackexchange.com . Anyway, suppose your only filesystem has gotten corrupted because a few sectors of the disk are bad. The OS will begin to log errors about corrupted directory entries, file block pointers that are out of bounds, etc. Processes will get i/o errors on open files, and may be killed if pages of the executable cannot be read from disk. Eventually, the OS may panic and write a crash dump. It wouldn't be good to write the dump to the filesystem, so it's usually written to a preconfigured crash device, typically the first swap partition.

Answer (score 2):

The kernel could on account of some bug spray random bits across the device the filesystem lives on and thus render the filesystem corrupt and quite possibly beyond repair.

Answer (score 0):

It does not help you are quoting that out of context.

What the text is probably alluding to, either before or after, is that the kernel places the file systems which it is working with in read-only mode in the event of a failure, to protect from corruption of said filesystems.